# If statements are showing weird results in a tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, if-statement

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I am using following if statements:

```
if ([taskitem.isCritical isEqualToString:@"iscritical"]){
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
else if ([taskitem.isUrgent isEqualToString:@"isurgent"]){
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
else if ([taskitem.isCompletedOK isEqualToString:@"iscompleted"]){
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    UIButton *doneButton4 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 12, 12)];
    [doneButton4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:doneButton4];
}
else {
       cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   }
    cell.textLabel.text = taskitem.taskName;
```

The problem is that the `if statements` are changing their behaviour if the user taps on any of the sections headers.

Do you find any error on my code that could be the reason of this weird behaviour or should I search for another reason in another method?

Comment: What `weird behavior` and what is the expected behavior ?

Comment: I think it is a problem of reusing the cells.

Comment: @MidhunMP, The expected behaviour is that cell.textLabel.text should have textColor and backGroundColor corresponding to the attribute values that are being compared. And doneButton4 should only be shown if the attribute isCompletedOK is equal to string @"isCompleted"... but after tapping on whatever section header, nothing is shown as expected....doneButton4 appears on all rows, etc...

Comment: @user2509601, what do you mean?

Comment: May be the issue is older, but I have detected it after including the third condition.

Comment: What's your code for reusing your cells?

Comment: Sorry, @user2509601, but I don't know what you mean when you say reusing the cells.

Comment: something like: `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    }`

Comment: @user2509601 yes, please take a look at my comment to the answer below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're probably having a cell reuse problem. You need to make sure that anything you do in one case, is done for each case (or undone).

For example, in first your three conditions, you set the text colour and the background colour. But in the fourth case (the else) you only set the text colour, leaving the background colour to be whatever it was on this cell the last time it was used. You need to set the background colour in the else case as well. (Optionally, you can set all items back to defaults before the if).

You have a second problem here, with the third case, that creates and adds a button to the cell. But in the other cases, you do not remove that button if it exists. So when you get a cell that was used for a completed item earlier, you'll end up with a button that doesn't belong. Even if the cell is used for another completed item, you'll get two buttons on the same cell. One on top of the other (so it likely won't be visible, but it's still a problem).

Try using this code:

```
UIButton* oldButton = [cell viewWithTag:253];
if (oldButton)
{
    [oldButton removeFromSuperview];
}

if ([taskitem.isCritical isEqualToString:@"iscritical"]) {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
else if ([taskitem.isUrgent isEqualToString:@"isurgent"]) {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
else if ([taskitem.isCompletedOK isEqualToString:@"iscompleted"]) {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    UIButton *doneButton4 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 12, 12)];
    [doneButton4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    doneButton4.tag = 253;
    [cell addSubview:doneButton4];
}
else {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

cell.textLabel.text = taskitem.taskName;
```

I don't recommend using tags like this in production code, but it's a quick way to see if it solves your problems. In real code, use a UITableViewCell subclass with a property for the done button that you can just show and hide. Ideally you're not creating it each time as that's an expensive operation and could slow down your scrolling performance.

Answer (score 0):

Create doneButton4 in (cell == nil) when reuse cells in table view

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
UIButton *doneButton4 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 12, 12)];
[doneButton4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell addSubview:doneButton4];
doneButton4.tag=100;
}

UIButton *doneButton4=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
doneButton4.hidden=YES;
if ([taskitem.isCritical isEqualToString:@"iscritical"]){
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
else if ([taskitem.isCritical isEqualToString:@"isurgent"]){
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
else if ([taskitem.isCritical isEqualToString:@"iscompleted"]){
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
doneButton4.hidden=NO;

}


else {
   cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
cell.textLabel.text = taskitem.taskName;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try your proposal, but I have already a good answer.